# Is blazor stable enough now for production or should i use MVC with a JS Framework instead?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

It has been awhile since blazor has been introduced and I was about to use Vue and ASP.NET Core MVC for my next project but I forgot Blazor exists. I was wondering if this framework is stable enough to invest? The project won't be something big though

Comment: Nobody can really answer what "stable enough for production" means to you, except you. Have you tried to do anything with it? Do you like working with it, as a framework?

Comment: @BriansaysReinstateMonica i haven't tried yet because i am confused with so many blazor versions, there is blazor web assemply that is still in preview until may 2020. So i don't know what should i use just to try out

Comment: The development model is different so I would check it out first. I like it, for on-prem intranet stuff (most of my projects these days) it's fantastic in my opinion and I would strongly recommend it if you're generally a Microsoft shop and are starting a new project. It's not like Vue where it's very easy to add a bit to an existing project.

Comment: @BriansaysReinstateMonica I see, our company is also full microsoft and our apps are all intranet small web apps. I will try give it a try and see how it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor Server Side is production ready, but Client Side is not as of today (12/12/19).